# Function not working when changing a class into an ID

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a function that toggles a div when clicked.

I found an existing Jfiddle that was sort of what I was after and tweaked it.

All is working fine except I need the .search-nav class to be an ID, but when I change it the function stops working.

I've tried various combinations but to no avail.

Working version is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rLmokp1/22/

```
$(function(){
  var mglass = $('.magnifying-glass');
  var div = $('.search-nav');

    mglass.click(function(){
        div.toggleClass('drop');
    });

});
```

Version with ID (not working) is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8rLmokp1/23/

```
$(function(){
  var mglass = $('.magnifying-glass');
  var div = $('#search-nav');

    mglass.click(function(){
        div.toggleClass('drop');
    });

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `#someId` has a greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.someClass`.

From the MDN:

> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> - Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g.,
>     [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> - ID selectors (e.g., #example).

You may change the selector in the CSS from

```
.drop
```

to

```
#search-nav.drop, .drop
```

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o56hfofz/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the specificity of the `drop` CSS class. As you changed the `search-nav` element to be styled by its `id` the id selector overrides any styles applied by a class. Therefore you need to increase the specificity of the `.drop` rules by prepending the id to it. Try this:

```
#search-nav.drop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rLmokp1/25/)

Answer (score 1):

That's specificity issue. You need to target using both `id` and `class` in CSS:

```css
#search-nav.drop {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You are using `height` in both `#search-nav` and `.drop`. Since `.drop` is less specific, it applies the properties of `#search-nav`. To increase the specificity, you need to add the the `id` selector as well, like `#search-nav.drop`.

This would help you understand:

[image]

**Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/npu8vkbo/**